# How do update the UI in a generic way from other threads/delegates?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created psedo code of what I would like to achieve. Inside of the SomeBLL().PerformBeginWork() threads will be created and maintained to do work. Using dot.net 4.0, what would be the best way to put this processing into an non-UI thread and still allow the assigned delegates to fire and update the UI in both a windows and web application without code modifications?

```
public class SomeBLL : BaseAsynWorker, IAsyncWorker
{
...makes threads and does work (if events are assigned then call them)
}
```

**On a web page**

---

```
SomeBLL sm=new SomeBLL();
sm.OnBeginWork+=ProcessUIUpdate;
sm.OnProgressUpdate+=ProcessUIUpdate;
sm.OnEndWork+=ProcessUIUpdate;
sm.OnHardError+=ProcessHardError;
SomeThreadClass.Spawn(sm.PerformBeginWork())
```

**In a non UI process**

---

```
SomeBLL sm=new SomeBLL();
sm.PerformBeginWork();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`SynchronizationContext` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx).